# How to append a default value in a query Row Source Type?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Form that has a Field where the Lookup is set as a Combox Box Display Control, a Table / Query Row Source Type and a Query for the Row Source. I am wondering how to append non-bounded elements to this Combo Box.

Right now, the Combobox looks something like:

```
Mark
Chris
Mary
Charles
```

I would like for it to read as:

```
NONE
Mark
Chris
Mary
Charles
```

Of course, NONE is not an actual entry in my table. I would just like to append it for redundancy purposes.

My query for the Row Source is:

```
SELECT StudentId, StudentName FROM Student ORDER BY StudentId
```

I have tried just appending it like:

```
SELECT StudentId, StudentName, "NONE" FROM Student ORDER BY StudentId
```

But it completely skips the NONE part.

So, I am wondering if there's a way to append non-bounded elements to a Combobox that IS properly bound to a result set of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `union all` :

```
SELECT s.*
FROM ((SELECT NULL AS StudentId, 'NONE' AS StudentName) UNION ALL
      (SELECT StudentId, StudentName 
       FROM Student
      ) 
    ) s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use UNION in SQL query to join non-existing value

```
SELECT 0 as StudentId, 'NONE' as StudentName FROM Dual
UNION
SELECT StudentId, StudentName FROM Student 
ORDER BY StudentId
```

Here Dual is table with one row